# How to install Epson WF2010 on Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am not an expert on Ubuntu but has been using it for the last 3 years.
I recently bought an Epson printer WF2010. On installing it the printer is recognised by the computer but on printing it prints rubbish!
On contacting Epson they sent me the following instructions:

and the following if using a 64 bit system:

epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Along with the following file regardless of system type:

epson-inkjet-printer-201211w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm

I installed epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1 through the software centre. But, cannot open it!
Not sure what to do with the file: epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `epson-inkjet-printer-201211w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm` file is going to be used for rpm-based distributions. If you can't install the .deb file through the Software Center, you can always attempt to install it via the command line using the dpkg package manager. Try running `sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` in the directory where the file is located.

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the applicable driver from epson 'epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb'.
Then I double clicked on the file and the installation started.
Then it asked for a mount of the Ubuntu installation disk in '/media/cdrom'.
I inserted the installation disk but unfortunately  it automounted to '/media/mycomputer/UBUNTU-disk-name'.
Therefore I opened the terminal and input after the'$ ' prompt:
sudo mount -B '/media/CCC/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64' '/media/cdrom'
To do so, please replace CCC with your computer name and 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64' with the name of your installation disk,
After this I continued the installation procedure but the installation failed.
Then I double clicked again the file: 'epson-inkjet-printer-201211w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb' but with the cdrom already mounted from the attempt before.
After this the installation ran perfectly, so I've also installed a driver to happiness with my printer to myself.